# Ignore comments in search VS2010 C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Is there any way to have Find ignore any occurrences of the query that are in a commented line? It's making some find / replace operations very time consuming.

Thanks,

PM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm wondering if the root cause of your trouble is that you have a lot of commented out historical code. That is the #1 thing I've seen that produces excessive comment lines. If so, use a proper version control system to preserve it, and then delete the old commented out code. This is a best practice.

Answer (score 0):

No easy way.  Find/Replace does support regular expression syntax, but setting up a regex that ignored commented code and still worked properly is beyond my tiny brain.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to say a similar feature used to exists in VS 2008 as "Search hidden text" checkbox in Find dialog, but it has been [removed](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/552975/no-more-search-hidden-text-in-find-and-replace-dialog) in VS 2010. Anyway, I'm not entirely sure having such a function would improve performance significantively. Even ignoring all text in comments from CPU consuming operations such verifying a regex, you always need to entirely read uncached files until EOF (and uncached means slow I/O operations are needed to load them in memory). No way to *really* not read "comments" unless files are cached in memory with an optimized structure, such a linked list of chunks of uncommented code.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a refactor operation *eg Rename*, then you can probably skip comments by using the refactor tools.